# Sum of squares of sum of squares function $r_2(n)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $r_2(n)$ denote the number of representations of $n$ as a sum of two squares.

What is known about the sum of squares of this function,

> $\sum_{i=1}^n r_2(i)^2$

In particular is anything known about the asymptotics as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: I believe that $r_k(i)$ is the number of ways to write $i$ as a sum of $k$ squares. (Cf. the [SquaresR](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html) function in Mathematica.)

Comment: Yep, I mistakenly put $r_k$ instead of $r_2$, fixed now =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asymptotics are known for all integer moments of $r_2$: for any $m \ge 1$, there is an explicit constant $a_m$ such that $\sum_{n \le x} r_2(n)^m \sim a_m\cdot x\,(\log x)^{2^{m-1}-1}$.  ($m=0$ also holds if we interpret $0^m$ as $0$.)

This result, including the precise constant (and a uniform generalization to other positive binary quadratic forms), can be found in V. Blomer and A. Granville, “Estimates for representation numbers of quadratic forms”, *Duke Math. J.* **135** (2006).  Here's the [PDF](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/quadraticforms.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Erick, I will check out the reference

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know
exact formulae for 
these types of sums,
I highly recommend
"Number Theory in the Spirit of Ramanujan"
by Bruce Berndt.

On page 56, a proof is given of
$r_2(n) = 4 \sum_{d|n, d\ odd} (-1)^{(d-1)/2}$.

You can do a Dirichlet multiplication
to get a double sum for $r_2^2(n)$.

By the way, after reading this book,
I am absolutely astounded
at how great a mathematician
Jacobi was.
He developed the $q$-series methods
that enabled him to
get explicit formulae for
the number of representations on any integer
as the sum of a number of squares
or triangular numbers.
Reading a list of his accomplishments
is, like wow!
He and Ramanujan would have gotten along famously.

Comment: Thanks for the post, will add to my reading list =)