# Sum of squares function $r_2(n)$ logarithmic moment asymptotics

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gaussian-integers

I am interested in asymptotics for the logarithmic moment (is that the right way to express this) of the sum of squares function $r_2(n)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function), that is: 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{N} r_2(n) \log(n)
\end{equation}
for large $N$.

I have seen similar questions relating to integer moments 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{N} r_2(n) n^m,
\end{equation}
how ever I am unsure how these extend in the $\log$ case.

Comment: Here, $r_2(n)$ is the number of ways to represent $n$ as a sum of two squares?

Comment: Sorry thats correct, I will edit to include a link to the wikipage for this function.

Comment: Maybe the information at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322086/sum-of-squares-of-sum-of-squares-function-r-2n provides some pointers.

Comment: Another link that may provide some tips is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710992/sum-of-squares-function-usually-larger-than-log-x1-2-epsilon

Comment: Had a chance to look at those links?

Comment: I did, but I'm not a number theorist at all, I'm a physicist working on a problem on a lattice and; so I'm not really sure how to extend the result.

Comment: It may be time to post to mathoverflow.net – if you do that, be sure to include a link at each post to the other one.