# sum of square of cube function $r_3(n)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I want to know that from [MSE on sum of squares of $r_2(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322086/sum-of-squares-of-sum-of-squares-function-r-2n), is it possible to have something like, ,where $r_3(n)$ denotes the number of ways $n=a^2+b^2+c^2$ for integers $a,b,c$ $$\sum_{n\le\mathcal N}r_3^2(n)\sim C\mathcal N^{3/2}\log^c\mathcal N$$
for some constant $c$? I think with the same argument with $3$ dimensional sphere (containing lattice points) we have something like the following? But I wonder about the case above $$\sum_{n\le \mathcal N}r_3(n)\sim \pi\mathcal N^{3/2}$$

Comment: Yes, this can be done. I don't know of a particularly easy way, but this on the edge of what the circle method can obtain for instance. I wrote [a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.10347.pdf) involving this as a piece. See the description and the cited works for various other approaches to this problem. The work of Muller is particularly relevant.

Comment: What is $r_3(n)$ (usually it is the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of 3 squares)

Comment: @reuns yes I mean as usual.

Comment: @davidlowryduda Really? that's a great news for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: @davidlowryduda A careful analysis of the growth and analytic continuation of $E_{s,\Gamma_0(4)}(z)=\sum_{\gamma \in <T>\backslash\Gamma_0(4)} \Im(\gamma z)^s$ may give the analytic continuation of $ \int_{\Gamma_0(4)\backslash \Bbb{H}} (
E_{s+1-k/2,\Gamma_0(4)}(z)y^{k/2}|\theta(z)|^6-
E_{s+1,\Gamma_0(4)}(z)) \frac{dxdy}{y^2}$ $=\Gamma(s)(4\pi)^{-s}\sum_{n\ge 1} r_k(n)^2 n^{-s}$ so that the asymptotic of $\sum_{n\le x} r_k(n)^2$ follows from a Tauberian theorem?