# sum of square of three squares function $r_3(n)$ II

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sums-of-squares

[image]

From [sum of square of cube function $r_3(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415927/sum-of-square-of-cube-function-r-3n), I believed that, as $r_k(n)$ denotes the number of ways that $n$ is the sum of $k$ squares, $$\sum_{n\le X} r_3(n)^2\asymp X^{3/2}\log^{C}X,...(*)$$
but with this image (from https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01303063?noAccess=true) shouldn't it means
$$\sum_{n\le X}r_3(n)^2\asymp X^2?$$

This seems pretty possible to me since
$\displaystyle r_4(n)=8\sum_{\substack{d|n \\ 4\not |d}} d\gg\sigma(n),$ thus
$$\sum_{n\le X}r_4(n)^2\gg \sum_{n\le X}n^2\asymp X^3.$$

So, is it really possible to attain $(*)$? Or actually we only have the magnitude of $X^2$? I can't grasp the paper but I need to use $(*)$ result and as Prof confirmed it before so I am not sure if I interpret the paper correctly.

Comment: the use of the word "cube"   is confusing. I suggest calling $r_3$  the "three squares function"

Comment: I believe that you have interpreted that paper correctly and (*) is not possible.